# Tizen Remote device manager isn't connecting with Samsung Smart TV

Tags: ubuntu, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I know this topic is already here and it was responded, but I did all steps that I saw on the answers and I still cannot make my PC(UBUNTU) connect with my Samsung smart tv(LT32E390S), I'm using Tizen 4.1, I can run emulator and it does recon when I ''scan'' through Remote Device Manager but when I toggle to switch ''ON'' it gives that message that [Error: failed to connect to remote target, 192.168.1.6, PORT 26101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovffq.png)

Any help I would appreciate, thanks

Comment: Hi Fabio, did you make sure that developer mode is enabled on the tv, that both your tv and dev machine are on the same subnet and that your dev machine's IP address is registered on theTV... and finally that you properly power-cycled your TV by holding the RC's power button for a few seconds ? if all of this is correct then you should be able to connect with sdb from your dev machine to your tv. If it still doesn't work then check you don't have a firewall blocking the traffic on port 26101 on your pc

Comment: Hi Xoundboy, thanks very much on trying to help me, appreciate it. Dude, I really dunno what is going on here, I did the what u have suggested, I've checked developer mode was on, checked both TV and dev machine was in the same subnet, reboot my TV and also I checked that my system is with firewall disabled. I think I gonna give up, it is so frustrating coz it is very easy and simple to do it so. Thanks anyway.